# Two questions in one sentence (embedded question)

Tags: questions

In a question like this (I took it from an English course):

> Can you tell me if **there's** anything you don't have any doubts about?

Is this correct? (grammatically speaking)

Because for me it seems that I should use the question structure in the second part two, looking like this:

> Can you tell me if **is there** anything you don't have any doubts
>   about?

Which one is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one interrogative structure, starting with Can you tell me, so everything else is in the affirmative:

Can you tell me if there's anything you don't have any doubts about?

Comment: Why remove the word *don't*? It's not wrong and removal reverses the question asked. The required answer is what is known definitively, not what is in doubt.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I removed 'don't' because you usually ask about things you do have doubts about.

Comment: @CathyGartaganis Around here we frequently have occasion to ask non-native speakers which parts of a difficult sentence they ***do*** understand, so we can pin down what their questions are about.

Comment: Also, changing the example given in the question can be confusing: the OP may believe that the example is actually ungrammatical and you can't grammatically use *don't,* whereas that's not the case at all. By changing the example, you're introducing a complication which is not related to the actual question.

Comment: Fair enough. Point taken. Thank you two for your input. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Partly related to: "changing subject and verb position..."

Related to original, direct questions, there are 2 types of them, depending on the beginning they have:

a) **Question word/phrase**  +  aux. + subject + main verb...

```
       Ex.  **WHERE**       DOES     HE        LIVE     ?( int.simple pres.)
```

b)           **Aux.**+ subject  +main verb...?

```
  Ex.    **Did**      he         know    the answer?
```

Trying to be more polite, you may use varied introductions to the questions above,(ex. Tell me../ I don't know../ Can you tell me...etc) what produces a change in the order and case of the   original question:

Ex. a)Can you tell me **where**    he   lives?(Interrog.S.Present)

```
        "          **Q.W.**  +  S  +(AFF. SIMPLE PRESENT)
```

After the introduction, **the question word is repeated**, immediately **followed** **by the subject** and **then the verb(s)**..in the original affirm.  tense.

Ex. b)              **Did** he know the answer? (interrog. simple past)

```
        Tell me **IF**  he     knew   the answer. (affirm simple past)     

                  **IF**  + S + (AFF.S.P.)...
```

In case b), we need an extra word to introduce the question after the introductory "Tell me..."(IF or WHETHER), IMMEDIATELY following the SUBJECT and next, the verb(s).

```
As you can see, interrogative tenses change to affirmative ones, when you use an introductory expression before.

Since SIMPLE PRESENT AFFIRMATIVE and SIMPLE PAST AFFIRMATIVE **do not take the** **auxiliary in the affirmative form,**(DO/DOES/DID). They disappear when you use an expression before the question.
```

All other tenses **always** use the auxiliary in aff./interrog. and negative cases.

**DO/DOES and DID** might appear in affirm SIMPLE PRESENT and SIMPLE PAST when you want to emphasize the action, so nothing doing with embedded questions, title the previous questions receive.

Comment: Can you tell me if there's anything you don't have any doubts about?